# RavenDB ETL to SQL, how to store entire document ('this') in jsonb column?

Tags: c#, postgresql, ravendb, npgsql, jint

In RavenDB 5.4+, I want to configure a [SQL ETL task](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/operations/maintenance/etl/add-etl#add-sql-etl) that offloads data to a PostgreSQL database, using Npgsql built-in factory for Raven. The issue I have is that I want the entire document (`this`) stored in a **jsonb** data column.

The question: how can I achieve storing the entire document, e.g. `this`, in the ETL transformation example below to Postgres?
My goal is not having to specify the fields/columns of object `Foo` manually.

Example Postgres table:

```sql
create table public.foo
(
    id   text,
    data jsonb
);
```

Example ETL transformation script, in RavenDB:

```js
loadToFoo ({
    id: id(this),
    data: this // <-- the issue
});
```

Which results in an exception:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42804: column "data" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text

I've tried the following alternatives:

```js
data: JSON.parse(this)

Error: 
    System.ArgumentException: Expected string but got Symbol
---
data: JSON.stringify(this)

Error:
    Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42804: column "data" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text
```

I'm also not sure if it's related to RavenDB's transform logic, or the solution should be thought of in the means of something from the Jint runtime, or in Postgres/Npgsql.

Comment: In Npgsql, you insert jsonb data by giving it a string but telling it that the type is jsonb (typically by setting NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb on your NpgsqlParameter). See [these docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#parameter-types) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @ShayRojansky - this is where the culprit lies; I don't know how to specify or define the type in the RavenDB ETL transformation script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell RavenDB what is the type that you want.
This is done by passing a value & type directly, like so:

```
loadToFoo ({
    id: id(this),
    data: {'Value:' this, 'Type': 'Jsonb'}
});
```

Comment: Important detail is that it **requires v5.4.5** or higher of RavenDB for this to work.